# QSqlTableModel with WHERE condition

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5, qsqltablemodel

How can i show a table with QTableView and WHERE condition ?

...WHERE numero_conta = 123;

```
        self.model = QSqlTableModel()
        self.model.setTable('historico')
        self.model.select()

        self.tab_extrato = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.tab_2)
        self.tab_extrato.setObjectName("tab_extrato")
        self.tab_extrato.setModel(self.model)
        self.tab_extrato.hideColumn(0)
        self.verticalLayout_9.addWidget(self.tab_extrato)
```

[link. the entire code](https://github.com/eduardo239/py-banki-project/blob/main/ui_/Minha_Conta.py)

[image]

Comment: What is the relation between the question about the select and that about the list?

Comment: `self.model.setQuery(QSqlQuery('SELECT * FROM historico WHERE numero_conta = 123')); self.model.select()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use "WHERE" then you want to filter the information so you must use the [`setFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter) method:

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel()
self.model.setTable('historico')
self.model.setFilter('numero_conta = 123')
self.model.select()
```